# BigQuery - Create view with Partition but base table doesn't have

Tags: google-bigquery

This may sound crazy, but I want to implement something like having a view with a partition.

### Background:

I had a table with a date partition on a column which is really huge in size. We are running data ingestion to this table at every 2mins interval. All the data loads are append-only. Ever load will insert 10k+ rows. After some time, we encountered the partition limitation issue.

```
message: "Quota exceeded: Your table exceeded quota for Number of partition modifications to a column partitioned table. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors"
```

**Root cause:(from GCP support team)**

> The root cause under the hood was that due to your partitioned tables
> have pretty granular partition for instance by minutes, hours or date,
> when the loaded data cover a wide range of partition period, the
> number of partition get modified will be high and above 4000. As per
> internal documentation, it was suggested the user who ran into this
> issue to consider making a less granular partition for instance change
> a date/hour/minute based partitioned table to a week based partitioned
> table. Alternatively split the load to multiple and hence limit the
> data range to cover less number of partitions that would be affected.
> This is the best recommendation I could have now.

So I'm planning to keep this table as un-partitioned and create a view(we need a view for eliminating the duplicates) and it should have parition. Is this possible? or any other alternate solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't partition a view, it's not physically materialized. Partitioning on day can be limiting with the 4000 limit, would year work? then you can use an integer partition:

```
create or replace table BI.test 
PARTITION BY RANGE_BUCKET(Year, GENERATE_ARRAY(2000, 3000, 1)) as
select 2000 as Year, 1 as value
union all
select 2001 as Year, 1 as value
union all
select 2002 as Year, 1 as value
```

Alternatively, I've used month (YYYYMM) or week (YYYYWW) to integer partition by which gets you around 40 years:

```
RANGE_BUCKET(monthasintegerfield, GENERATE_ARRAY(201612, 205712, 1))
```